# How does scrolling work in the Google+ iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios5

Here is the main scroller. The stream view. But how did they implement this?

My guess:
There are several views/tableview in a single UiScrollBar with paging enabled. 
The "incoming circles nearby" view is also a UIScrollBar containing UIlables which react to UITouchMoved. But how can it be so fast and not laggy even if there are several views/tableview in a scrollbar?

Is there any external api similar to this one? I would like to implement it in one of my apps.

Thank you!

http://www8.pcmag.com/media/images/264656-google-mobile-app-stream.jpg[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fast because it's efficient. The only pre-loaded views are the ones to the left and right of the current view. Once you move to the next view, one view is unloaded and the following one is loaded so scrolling is seamless.

If you try and scroll it really quickly without you should be able to get one of the views to start bouncing (i.e there's nothing to scroll to), meaning that the following view hasn't been loaded and the scroll view content offset not adjusted.

It looks like they are using a scrollview with different tableviews inside it for each of the view options (Circles, Incoming, Nearby...). Paging is enabled and scrolling is only possible in one direction at a time.

[edit]
By the way check out some of Apple's WWDC videos from 2010 and 2011 as there are some good examples there on how to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rog. I will definitely check those videos out. Yes you are right about the three preloaded views. I tried to scroll fast and sometimes a black/nil view would appear for 0.1 sec. How do you think the viewOptions is implemented? If you scroll 320px to the left, the "Nearby" label comes in the middle. How does that work? BTW you have wonderful articles around the web. Thanks mate ;)

Comment: the label would be pretty easy, you simply offset the content based on the scrollview contentOffset in the `scrollView:didScroll:` method.